# How to configure an Azure Function behind a VNet to receive alerts from Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vnet, azure-alerts

I want to configure an action to send the fired alert to an Azure Function which is behind a VNet.
I tried to configure the action to send the fired alert to an Azure Function which is behind a VNet. But it failed and there were no error details. I tried with an Azure Function which is NOT behind a VNet and it worked. I am expecting it should work with the Azure Function in a VNet. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Where are you firing the alert from?

Comment: The alert is fired from a log analytics workspace. It is a "custom log search" type alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure private links to allow Log Analytics workspace to send alerts to your VNET.

There is a video showing how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22AmkJofT7g